# Mongoid document Time to Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Is there a way to set time to live for a document and then it gets destroyed. I want to create guest users that are temporary per session, so after a week the document gets removed automatically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MongoDB (version 2.2 and up) actually has a special index type that allows you to specify a TTL on a document (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).  The database removes expired documents for you--no need for cron jobs or anything.

Mongoid supports this feature as follows:

```rb
index({created_at: 1}, {expire_after_seconds: 1.week})
```

The `created_at` field must hold date/time information. Include `Mongoid::Timestamps` in your model to get that for free.

UPDATE:

If you want to expire only a subset of documents, then you can create a special date/time field that is only populated for that subset.  Documents with no value or a non-date/time value in the indexed field will never expire.  For example:

```rb
# Special date/time field to base expirations on.
field :expirable_created_at, type: Time

# TTL index on the above field.
index({expirable_created_at: 1}, {expire_after_seconds: 1.week})

# Callback to set `expirable_created_at` only for guest roles.
before_create :set_expire, if: "role == :guest"
def set_expire
  self.expirable_created_at = Time.now
  return true
end
```

Comment: Ok, but what i only need TTL only on a range of documents in my case guest users. user.role = guest and i don't think this function does that

Comment: I didn't realize you only needed to expire a subset of a collection.  Here's an idea:  because the index requires a date/time value, just set the indexed field to `nil` for non-guest users and they will never expire.  In this case, I'd create a special date/time field (instead of using the standard `created_at`).

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example for expiring only guest roles.

Comment: no problem.  FYI: For correctness, I updated the code example to only set the timestamp when the record is new, since you probably don't want it to reset whenever the record is updated :)

Comment: Incase it helps anyone else, I had to use `expireAfterSeconds: 604800` instead of `expire_after_seconds: 1.week`

Comment: @nates `1.week` is rails magic. I used it in my example because the OP tagged this question with `ruby-on-rails`. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Typo in the post: TTL indexes were added in Mongo 3.2, not 2.2.

Comment: @AlexSharp TTL indexes were add in 2.2. See: https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.2/core/indexes/#index-feature-ttl

Answer (score -2):

First you should add `include Mongoid::Timestamps` to your model.

Second you should add a cron job or a worker of some sort that will run (if you don't want perhaps you can use this gem https://github.com/daddye/foreverb)

And then you can easily set up a check for the gem to see

```
if model.created_at > 1.week.ago
  model.destroy
end
```